# Picture not geotagged altough GPS tag option activated?

Tags: geotagging

On my Huawei P8 Lite running the stock ALE-L21C432B194 Lollipop 5.0.1 firmware, pictures don't seem to be geotagged although I have the "GPS tag" option activated in the camera's Settings:

[image]

When opening a file in either PaintShop Pro or IrfanView, no geolocation info are available.

Any idea why?

Thank you.

Comment: Not familiar with the icons on the top of your screen shot, but is your GPS turned on, high accuracy mode?

Comment: @Gulbahar does that mean your issue is solved? If so, mind to write an answer explaining how?